# Error al cerrar ventana creada con tkinter mediante botón

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, canvas

Intento hacer una interfaz gráfica para mostrar un mapa que se dibujará de acuerdo con los lugares seleccionados. El código para mi UI es:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk as ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master

        self.init_window()


    def init_window(self):

        # Cambioa el titulo de la ventana
        self.master.title("Aviones")

        # controla el espacuo que tomara en la ventana
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # Crea instancia del boton
        quitButton = Button(self, text="Cerrar", command=self.client_exit)
        profunda = Button(self, text="Profundidad")
        anchura = Button(self, text="Anchura")

        # Coloca el boton
        quitButton.place(x=700, y=500)
        profunda.place(x=590, y=500)
        anchura.place(x=500, y=500)

        # label
        o = Label(self, text="Origen")
        d = Label(self, text="Destino")

        # Coloca labels
        o.place(x=100, y=475)
        d.place(x=350, y=475)

        # Spinbox
        origen = ttk.Combobox(self, values=["1", "2", "3"])
        origen.set("1")
        origen.place(x=50, y=500)

        destino = ttk.Combobox(self, values=["1", "2", "3"])
        destino.set("1")
        destino.place(x=300, y=500)

        # mapa
        fig = Figure()  ## here
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)  ## here
        my_map = Basemap(projection='ortho', lat_0=37, lon_0=9,
                     resolution='l', area_thresh=1000.0,ax=ax1)

        my_map.drawcoastlines()
        my_map.drawcountries()
        my_map.fillcontinents(color="coral")
        my_map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master = self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

        # frame
        #control = Frame(self)
    def client_exit(self):
        exit()



fig = Figure()  ## here
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(234)  ## here


root = Tk()

# tamano de la ventana
root.geometry("800x600")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Actualmente me crea esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al presionar 'Cerrar' me arroja este error:

> Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate
>     This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>     Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un título más descriptivo a la pregunta? El problema no está relacionado con basemap o matplotlib. De esta forma ayudarás a otros a encontrar mejor tu problema y podría ser más útil para todos.

Answer (score 2):

Bienvenido a stackoverflow Manuel;

`exit()` no es la manera apropiada de hacer esto, deberias usar `self.destroy()` si deseas cerrar solo el `Frame (app)` o `self.master.destroy()` si quieres cerrar la ventana completa (`root`):

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk as ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):

        # Cambioa el titulo de la ventana
        self.master.title("Aviones")

        # controla el espacuo que tomara en la ventana
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # Crea instancia del boton
        quitButton = Button(self, text="Cerrar", command=self.client_exit)
        profunda = Button(self, text="Profundidad")
        anchura = Button(self, text="Anchura")

        # Coloca el boton
        quitButton.place(x=700, y=500)
        profunda.place(x=590, y=500)
        anchura.place(x=500, y=500)

        # label
        o = Label(self, text="Origen")
        d = Label(self, text="Destino")

        # Coloca labels
        o.place(x=100, y=475)
        d.place(x=350, y=475)

        # Spinbox
        origen = ttk.Combobox(self, values=["1", "2", "3"])
        origen.set("1")
        origen.place(x=50, y=500)

        destino = ttk.Combobox(self, values=["1", "2", "3"])
        destino.set("1")
        destino.place(x=300, y=500)

        # mapa
        fig = Figure()  ## here
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)  ## here
        my_map = Basemap(projection='ortho', lat_0=37, lon_0=9,
                     resolution='l', area_thresh=1000.0,ax=ax1)

        my_map.drawcoastlines()
        my_map.drawcountries()
        my_map.fillcontinents(color="coral")
        my_map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master = self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

        # frame
        #control = Frame(self)

    def client_exit(self):
        self.master.destroy()


fig = Figure()  ## here
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(234)  ## here


root = Tk()
# tamano de la ventana
root.geometry("800x600")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

De esta forma no debería darte problemas, probado bajo Python 2.7.12, 64 bits en Windows.

Answer (score 0):

en lugar de usar exit() para cerrar una ventana debes hacerlo con el nombre de la ventana que cerraras punto destroy(). como en el siguiente ejemplo

```
def client_exit(self):
        self.master.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter tiene una función ya incluida que nos permite acabar con el programa, que es destroy(), por ejemplo si yo tengo una ventana principal llamada "wn", entonces para acabar con esa ventana principal se debería poner "wn.destroy()", y listo, así de fácil, aqui te dejo un código para que pruebes lo que te digo:

```
from tkinter import *

def salir():
    
    wn.destroy()

wn= Tk()

Button(wn, text= "salir", command= salir).pack()

wn.mainloop()
```

python 3.9.1
(este comando sirve para cualquier ventana que quieras cerrar)